# Having trouble passing Javascript array of objects to MVC3 controller, works with WCF service, any ideas?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having problems passing a javascript array to an MVC3 controller, not sure what I am doing wrong but this code does work with standard WCF service.

```
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        Poster();
    });
});

function Poster() {
    var data = [];
    data.push(new WidgetProperty("test1", "value1"));

    alert(data.length);

    $.post("Home/Test", {test : data});
}

function WidgetProperty(name, value) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Value = value;
}
```

and controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(WidgetProperty[] test)
{
    return View("About");
}


public class WidgetProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas why the object that comes to the controller has null values for the properties? Checked with fiddler and it appears it passing the correct values.

Thanks!

Comment: make sure the post's datatype is JSON...also try explicity stringifying the array using JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JSON.stringify() on your data before you post it, and since you know the data type is JSON, it is best to specify that the data being posted is JSON.

```
$.post("Home/Test", {test : JSON.stringify(data) }, "json");
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aXEDe/3/)

**Edit**:

I researched this a little more and it seems that you need to include `contentType: "application/json"` in order for this to work in mvc3:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Home/Test",
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     success: function(data){},
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json"
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, however now the veriable test coming to controller is null, before atleast it had object reference with properties being null.

Comment: If you check the post data in firebug, what does it look like?

Comment: test [{"Name":"test1","Value":"value1"},{"Name":"test2","Value":"value2"}]
Source
test=%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22test1%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22value1%22%7D%2C%7B%22Name%22%3A%22test2%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22value2%22%7D%5D

Comment: Josh, thank you I really appreciate your help it works! Not sure while it is so sensitive on the syntax, it might be something to do with jQuery.